# Freeagent authentication with accesstoken

Tags: api

I go through with https://dev.freeagent.com/docs/oauth for implement the API.

But not able to get the access-token. I got the code but the process to get access-token I face below issue.

**Request:**

```
POST /v2/token_endpoint HTTP/1.1

Host: api.sandbox.freeagent.com

grant_type: authorization_code

code: 4/z7IBgRS-Pjx6y5-djE-uaRAjqeYleIdVCyjwiFgnfdg

redirect_uri: https://google.com

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8

client_id: 3go0PEltpEHFFzEOdliIzQ

client_secret: OLefVbuT3LhEqpMh-2iq3w

Cache-Control: no-cache

Postman-Token: d47f46b7-9e1d-2969-8a40-53ee2120d5c2
```

**Response:**

```
{

  "error": "invalid_request"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### [FreeAgent Quick Start Guide](https://dev.freeagent.com/docs/quick_start)

It's very condensed and not entirely clear but I followed along with the [FreeAgent Quick Start Guide](https://dev.freeagent.com/docs/quick_start) and eventually was able to get the Access Token as well as the Refresh Token.

Using the [Google OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/#step3&url=https%3A//&content_type=application/json&http_method=GET&useDefaultOauthCred=unchecked&oauthEndpointSelect=Custom&oauthAuthEndpointValue=https%3A//api.sandbox.freeagent.com/v2/approve_app&oauthTokenEndpointValue=https%3A//api.sandbox.freeagent.com/v2/token_endpoint&includeCredentials=unchecked) I was able to authenticate myself and receive the various responses.

It's all in their guide.

Good luck!